# Dúvida em relação aos eventos do Task Schedule- Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Já procurei na documentação e outros fóruns, mas não achei a resposta.

Seguinte, a frequência que um tarefa é executada começa normalmente em que momento? 
Sei que o método `->hourly()` é executado a cada hora, mas em que momento? É executado, por exemplo em 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, etc. Ou, dependendo da hora que foi programado, pode ser executado em, por exemplo, 13:05, 14:05, 15:05, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `->hourly();` corre ao inicio de cada hora. 13:00,14:00 etc.

Para correr a um minuto específico existe outro método: `->hourlyAt(17);`

Answer (score 1):

Ele se baseia no [`crontab`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) (para Linux) que é executado a cada minuto:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

O [`->hourly();`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options) é executado a cada hora fechada do sistema, com base no que está definido no Crontab,

Por exemplo quando quiser rodar um script todos os dias as 10:30, basta definir: `->dailyAt('10:30');`

A documentação é bem completa, as vezes um pouco confusa, segue o link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling